# unexpected token error as and Undefined variable $collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm just following a tutorial however, it has a simple error that says unexpected token. What can I do to remove this error.

What Im trying to achieve is I want to retrieve the data from my realtime firebase database however, it shows an error.

here's the notification blade:

```
@section('title', 'Notification')
@include('partials.header')

<body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0" style="background: #2F3192;">
            @include('partials.side-menu')
        </nav>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-white shadow mb-4 topbar static-top" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                    @include('partials.top-bar')
                </nav>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h3 class="text-dark mb-4">Notifications</h3>
                </div>

                @if (session('status'))
                    <h4 class="alert alert-warning mb-2  ">{{session('status')}}</h4>
                @endif

                <div style="margin-left: 18px;padding-left: 9px;margin-right: 15px;padding-right: 17px;">
                    
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1" style="color: var(--bs-nav-tabs-link-active-color);">Notifications</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2" style="color: var(--bs-nav-link-disabled-color);">Push</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="tab-1">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header py-3">
                                    <p class="text-primary m-0 fw-bold"><a href="exportcsv_inventory.html"></a></p>
                                    <div class="d-flex" style="padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;margin-bottom: -20px;">
                                        <div class="order-first" style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding-bottom: 24px;padding-right: 0px;margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 972px;"><a href="notifications-recdelete.html"><img src="{{ asset('build/img/vectors/restore%20icon.png?h=abe1ada3a775349b97bc374a568c633f')}}"></a></div>
                                        <div class="d-flex order-last" style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 374px;margin-top: 6px;padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 28px;"><img src="{{ asset('build/img/vectors/bin.png?h=79a6fc27e815e003168433b9f14f48ce')}}" width="17" height="17"><input type="checkbox" style="padding-left: 21px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 6px;padding-right: 34px;margin-top: 2px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr></tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @forelse ($collection as $key => $item)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="margin-right: -8px;padding-right: 7px;margin-left: -30px;padding-left: 36px;">Cell 3</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @empty
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="7">No record found</td>
                                                    </tr>  
                                                @endforelse
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="{{ url('push')}}" method="POST" style="margin-right: 308px;width: 782.2px;min-width: -24px;">
                                        @csrf

                                        <h5 style="border-color: rgb(14,17,44);"><strong>Title</strong></h5>
                                        <input name="notif_title" class="form-control" type="text">
                                        <h5 style="border-color: rgb(14,17,44);padding-top: 0px;margin-top: 15px;"><strong>Description</strong></h5>
                                        <textarea name="notif_desc" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px;text-align: right;margin-left: 458px;background: #2f3192;">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" style="margin-top: 11px;">
                                <div class="card-header py-3">
                                    <h3>History</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr></tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="margin-right: -8px;padding-right: 7px;margin-left: -30px;padding-left: 36px;">Cell 3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="bg-white sticky-footer" style="margin-top: 28px;">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="text-center my-auto copyright"><span>Copyright © Villman 2022</span></div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div><a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    </div>

@include('partials.footer')
```

my controller:
NavBar.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Database;

class NavBar extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Database $database){
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->tablename = 'push_notif';
    }
    
    public function dboard(){
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function notif(){

        $collection = $this->database->getReference($this->tablename);
        return view('notification', compact('push_notif'));
    }

    public function inv(){
        return view('inventory');
    }

    public function order(){
        return view('order');
    }

    public function ship(){
        return view('shipping');
    }

    public function prod(){
        return view('product');
    }

    public function carou(){
        return view('carousel');
    }

    public function report(){
        return view('reports');
    }

    public function settings(){
        return view('settings');
    }
}
```

The error just looks like this when I hover.[image]

Comment: add relevant controller code in your question.

Comment: Can you share the complete error?

Comment: For us to help, could you share the code from the controller where you return the data to the view?

Comment: Can you add your entire `blade` view code please. It might be you have another `@` directive or similar somewhere in the file that is actually causing this.

Comment: Is it an error in your IDE only? Because that looks correct to me.

Comment: @GertB. that's what I'm thinking too. What do you mean by IDE? I'm using Visual Studio Code for Laravel 9 with firebase

Comment: @OverleyLoley I'm not using Visual Studio myself, but it looks like it does not understand the `@forelse` blade directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the errors is the "PHP Tools" extension. I uninstalled it and the 100k+ errors disappeared.